# Django auto delete function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a random discount code generator in django. And I have created a model for it in which there's an expiration date field 'valid_to'. I want the function to delete the coupon object when the time is now.

```
models.py
class Coupon(models.Model):     
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=20))
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=15, validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(100)])


    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.code is None or self.code == "":
            self.code = code_generator()
        super(Coupon, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need for `active` field. When you validate the discount code, check if the current date is in between `valid_from` and `valid_to`. If you don't know how to do it, then I will post an answer.

Comment: @Ambitions yes please share your answer with me.

Comment: @AKX has answered your question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

First – your `valid_to` expression is faulty; it should be wrapped in a function, so it's correctly evaluated. Right now it's evaluated once on import time.

```
def compute_default_valid_to():
    return datetime.now() + timedelta(days=20)

# ...

class Coupon(models.Model):
    # ...
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(default=compute_default_valid_to)
```

Secondly, there's no way to automagically run code. You might just want a management command or other scheduled task to run, say, nightly and do

```
Coupon.objects.filter(valid_to__lte=now()).update(active=False)
```

(or `.delete()` if that's your business logic).

You'll probably also want a custom manager that contains the business logic to only return valid coupons:

```
class CouponQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def valid(self):
        return self.filter(active=True, valid_from__lte=now(), valid_to__gte=now())

# ...

class Coupon(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = CouponQuerySet.as_manager()

# ...

valid_coupon = Coupon.objects.valid().get(code=user_code_here)
```

Comment: @I'm gettign an error "Cannot serialize function: lambda"

Comment: My bad. It needs to be a named function.